# Knockout.js nested sortable bindings

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I am working with the knockout.js sortable plugin; however, I ran into a problem that I have so far been unable to solve. I have two sortable bindings, one for buckets and another for bucketItems. I am able to reorder bucketItems between buckets; however, I am unable to reorder buckets. Would you have any idea why this would be? I am also using nested with bindings, but as far as I can tell, this is not what is causing problems.

I would greatly appreciate any insight you have to offer.

Comment: please post your code and the plugin you are using

Comment: due to certain reasons, i can't post my code; however, i was able to narrow down the scope of my problem. i have an array of bucketIds and when I apply sortable to it, it doesn't bind correctly. unfortunately, i still don't know why it won't bind. (i'm using knockout.js-sortable plugin created by ryan neimeyer)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know your exact structure, but you can use the `connectClass` option to control which sortable lists are connected.  For example, if you did this:

```
<ul data-bind="sortable: { data: buckets, connectClass: 'buckets' }">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <ul data-bind="sortable: { data: items, connectClass: 'items' }">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You would only be able to drop a bucket within buckets and an item within items. The plugin automatically adds the class to the parent element.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YaLgL/

If you did not want to be able to sort items between buckets, then you could apply a unique `connectClass` to each like:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/czNe8/

Comment: How do you get this to work when you do not want an item to be sortable but the others to be? I tried use this an although the item was not reorderable, The whole parent UL moved when I tried and that in turn made the UL's parent LI be reordered (its weird).

Comment: @Phil- can you maybe put what you are trying to do in a jsFiddle with some notes? There is likely a way to make it work, but I am not positive that I am on top of your scenario. Thanks!

Comment: I added a fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/zoldello/8hvXN/2/

What is happening is that when I try to move the NOT MOVABLE item, the entire item is selected. Try holding down your mouse on the NOT MOVABLE and notice the whole container move. Is there a way to stop this issues?

Comment: you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zRrAC/ where you handle mousedown on the element and prevent it from bubbling.

Comment: @niemeyer , i am getting this exception on browser console

Your version of jQuery.tmpl is too old. Please upgrade to jQuery.tmpl 1.0.0pre or later.

can u help me ??

I am using Knockout-3.1.0.js  and knockout-sortable.js(which is prepared by tou)