# KnockoutJS and Nested Sortable List (Two-Dimensional)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, tree, nested, knockout-2.0

I am looking for a way to implement a simple nested/nestable tree structure in KnockoutJS; and it should only allow two levels.

What I found so far is this (and a range of very similar approaches here on SO): [Knockout.js nested sortable bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348270/knockout-js-nested-sortable-bindings)

However, in this example - and the others, "Containers" cannot become "Children" and vice versa.

Basically, I am looking for a structure like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uhVAW/2/

I.e. it will ultimately render a list with two levels: parent categories and their children.

My tree-structure in the Knockout ViewModel takes this shape (without all the updating logic):

```
 var VM = function(cats)
 {
    this.categories = ko.observableArray(cats); // bound to the list
 }

 var Category = function
 {
    this.name = ko.observable();
    this.children = ko.observableArray([]); // if exists (i.e. if the cat is a parent), this is bound to a list within the <li>
 }
```

So, in essence:

1. Sorting parent level
2. Sorting children within parents
3. Children can become parents & vice versa
4. Only allowing n-levels of nesting (2 in my case)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple tree view using [knockout-sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) with recursive templates: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Lqttf/

The view model would just look like:

```
var TreeItem = function(name, children) {
   this.name = ko.observable(name);
   this.children = children && ko.observableArray(children);
};

ko.applyBindings({
    root: new TreeItem("root", [
       new TreeItem("A", [
          new TreeItem("A1"),
          new TreeItem("A2")
       ]),
       new TreeItem("B", [
          new TreeItem("B1"),
          new TreeItem("B2")
       ])
    ])
});
```

The view would look like:

```
<script id="nodeTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a>
        <div data-bind="if: children">
           <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: $data.children }"></ul>            
        </div>
    </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'nodeTmpl', data: root }"></ul>
```

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic - thanks a bunch! I have slightly modified it to make sure there's always at least an empty observableArray. Otherwise one cannot add items to empty lists: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqttf/1/ | 
That being said: would you have any pointers as to how I could only allow two levels? Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I was being a bit slow. I could bind allowDrop to an observable boolean which returns "false" from the second level onwards. :-)

Comment: @niemeyer , sir first of all thanks for your solutions related to KNOCKOUT-SORTABLE , KNOCKOUT-RECURSIVE  .

sir, i am also looking for exact solution which u mentioned above , i wnat one solution to calculate total for each Node.

each node has two properties ( title , amount) , so i need to display sum of amounts(childrens) on parent node .